# How to grep a line if it include some strings?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

I have a settings file named ***student***

```
grade1 class1 11 student
grade1 class1 12 student
grade2 class1 21 student
grade2 class2 22 student
......
```

Now I create a ***test.sh*** file to read student. If input gradename and studentnumber, the line include two strings will be copied to ***student_copy***. The code will be like:

```
echo Input gradename and studentnumber
read gradename
read studentnumber

if (input gradename and studnetnumber);
then
    echo "the line include them" >> student_copy
```

For example:

```
if (input grade1 and 11);
then 
    echo grade1 class1 11 student >> student_copy
```

Comment: example output will help us to understand it better.

Comment: If you write your script to ask questions rather than take arguments on the command line, it can only easily be used interactively.  If, instead, you make it take arguments from the command line (e.g. with `gradename="$1"` and `studentnumber="$2"` in the script to use the first and second arguments) it can be used by other scripts.  You can also make it print a help message if an argument is missing or invalid or is equal to `-h` or `--help`.

Answer (score 6):

`grep` doesn't do logical **AND** operations (e.g. `match patternA AND patternB`), the closest you can come is to construct a longer regexp that matches any one of the possible variations (e.g. `grep -E 'patternA.*patternB|patternB.*patternA'`).  This gets very clumsy and unwieldy if you have lots of patterns to match.

The easiest way to do what you want is to use a scripting language like `awk` or `perl` instead of `grep`.

e.g. the following `awk` one-liner will match any lines where both patterns appear.

```
awk '/patternA/ && /patternB/'
```

Any of the pattern-matches can be inverted too, for example if you want to match any line containing patternA that does not contain patternB (i.e. an **AND NOT** operation):

```
awk '/patternA/ && ! /patternB/'
```

Note: one naive approach is to use `grep patternA | grep patternB` (or `grep patternA | grep -v patternB`) - that **does** achieve a logical AND (or AND NOT) but at the cost of running multiple `grep` commands rather than a single `awk` or `perl` command.

Comment: hi, I put my attempts below, could you kindly help? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Say we want to find lines with `grade1` and `11`:

Sample data (not the same as in the question) and search keys:

```
$ cat student
grade1 class1 11 student
grade1 class1 111 student
grade11 class1 21 student
grade12 class2 22 student
$ grade=grade1
$ num=11
```

Straightforward grep to look for the given strings, note the `\<`/`\>` anchors that match word edges. This needs them in order:

```
$ grep "^$grade\>.*\<$num\>" student
grade1 class1 11 student
```

Or with `-w` to match full words.

```
$ < student grep -w "$grade" |grep -w "$num"
grade1 class1 11 student
```

Both of the above might match any similar looking words elsewhere on the lines, so maybe it's better to do it with awk and compare just the appropriate fields. This assumes the fields are separated by whitespace, so they can't contain any white space in itself.

```
$ awk -vg=$grade -vn=$num '$1 == g && $3 == n' student
grade1 class1 11 student
```

If you need to have fields with spaces, then it would be best to have a distinct separator, like tab.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i run 

`awk -vs=$studentnumber -vg=$gradename '$1 == g && $3 == s {print $0}' student > student2 `       it's working perfectly!!!

Answer (score 0):

I run this command below,

```
awk '{
if ($1!="grade1" || $3!=11)
print "###";
else
print $0;
}' student
```

the output is

```
grade1 class1 11 student
###
###
###
```

which is the expected output

but if I run ***test.sh***, the code is below:

```
read -p "Enter gradename: " gradename
read -p "Enter studentnumber: " studentnumber

echo "gradename = $gradename"
echo "studentnumber = $studentnumber"
awk '{
if ($1!="$gradename" || $3!=$studentnumber)
print "###";
else
print $0;
}' student > student2

cat student2
```

then the output will be:

```
Enter gradename: grade1
Enter studentnumber: 11
gradename = grade1
studentnumber = 11
###
###
###
###
```

It's very weird

Comment: This isn't an answer, so should be edited in to your question above or posted as a new question.  The problem, though, is that because the `awk` script is inside single-quotes, `$studentnumber` is not replaced with the shell variable as you expect (variable interpolation does not happen inside single quotes).  The easies/simplest solution is to add `studentnumber="$studentnumber"` either immediately before or immediately after the `student` filename on the `awk` command line.  That sets an awk variable of the same name  to have the value of the shell variable.

Comment: i just noticed the same is true for `$gradename`.  @ilkkachu 's answer shows another way to pass variables from shell to `awk`.  You can either  add `awkvariable=value` as many times as you want after the quote-enclosed awk script, or you can use `-v awkvariable=value` before the script.  works the same either way.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. This is the first time I posted question on stackovflow.   i run 

`awk -vs=$studentnumber -vg=$gradename '$1 == g && $3 == s {print $0}' student > student2 `       it's working perfectly!!!

Answer (score 0):

Below awk one liner i have used to find the same and its works fine

```
 for i  in `awk '{print $1}' student.txt| sed -r "s/\s+//g"| sed '/^$/d'| sort -u` ; do awk -v i="$i" '$1 ~ i && $3 == "11"{print $0}'  student.txt ; done
```

I Checked for studentnumber 11 as constant so i mentioned $3==11 in script.

grade1 and grade2 as variable in "i"

You can change the student Number as per your requirement. Change the value of $3== "New  Student number" as per requirement